# Using trigger I want to create a case everytime an account is created

Tags: apex, trigger, case, account

I am just getting started with triggers. I want to create a `Case` every time an `Account` record is created. Can someone tell me how to write the logic for this?

Comment: Why a case and not a task ?

Comment: Hi Harvey, welcome to the SF SE site! It may be helpful to quickly read over the How to Ask guide: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask so we can give a better answer to your question.

Comment: @Br0k3nL1m1ts FYI you can type `[ask]` and it will display [ask].

Comment: @AdrianLarson Didn't know that, Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi Brovasi, Task also works. Can you help me with it. Thank you all

Answer (score 7):

Just use `Process Builder`. There is no readily apparent reason you need to use a trigger for this functionality.

1. Navigate to `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Process Builder`.
2. Click <kbd>New</kbd>.
   Fill in `Process Name` > `New Account Case`.
   No need to fill in `API Name`, it will auto-populate.
   You may fill in an optional `Description`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
3. Click <kbd>+ Add Object</kbd>.
   Select `Account`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
4. Click <kbd>+ Add Criteria</kbd>.
   Fill in `Criteria Name` > `All`
   Select `No criteria—just execute the actions!`.
5. Click <kbd>+ Add Action</kbd>.
   Select `Action Type` > `Create a Record`.
   Fill in `Action Name` > `Create Case`.
   Select `Record Type` > `Case`.
   Populate field data as desired.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
6. Click <kbd>Activate</kbd>.

Comment: I followed those steps as explained an I think that there are some parts missing because it is not working.

Comment: @Viasur It works for me exactly as described.

Comment: @Adrian, your answer is not completed and it is not working. I voted down because is not solving the initial question, nothing else. I tried your solution and is not working at all.

Comment: @Viasur That sounds like a flaw in your implementation then...I tested it multiple times and it works. Created a `Case` every time. Did you by chance forget the final step?

Comment: @Adrian Larson, flaw? there is not flaw here. Please, add step by step of what it is what you are doing because on your initial answer there is something missing.

Comment: @Viasur The only missing step was giving the criteria block a name. The only way I can get this flow to *not* create a record is by deactivating it.